# "Также" слитно — ошибка?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Простите за дурацкий вопрос. Это точно ошибка на скрине из "Семнадцати мгновений весны" или всё-таки раньше были не совсем такие же правила, как сейчас?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

В дополнении к данному ранее ответу сошлюсь на авторитетный источник — словарь Кузнецова.

> **Также как**, в зн. союза. *Он владеет французским, также как и немецким.*

Очевидно, что если в приведенном примере написать "так же" раздельно, смысл предложения существенно изменится (upd. правда, тогда и запятая переместится; так что аргумент "двусмысленность" здесь не работает).

В нашем случае, очевидно, имеется в виду, что **что-то беспокоит и Даллеса, и нас тоже**. Поэтому здесь слитное написание использовано корректно.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, всё-таки предлагается слитное написание в словарях именно в таком случае.

Comment: Что ж, хорошо, что находится и словарное подтверждение простому здравому смыслу, хотя первое издание этого словаря было в 1998 году. К поискам оправдания написанному в переводе письма из _телефильма_ побуждает уже то обстоятельство, что в давние времена на телевидении был строгий филологический контроль (людей буквально могли "депремировать" за ляпы, которые сейчас проходят с легкостью и, к сожалению, незаметно для многих); сам Розенталь тогда редактировал справочники для Гостелерадио. Вот и здесь всё оказалось безупречно.

Answer (score 2):

Не могу найти этого в правилах, но логика слитного написания могла бы здесь опираться на различение смыслов "**как и мы тоже**" (присоединение, наш случай) и "**в той же мере, что и мы**" (сравнение). В правилах же для проверки обычно предлагается прямолинейная подстановка *слова* "**также**" вместо "**тоже**" или замена на "и" (если она возможна, то слитно) - этим выясняют, союз там или наречие. В словарях приводится только "так же(,) как и" с раздельным написанием, хотя в современных книгах встречается иное.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Мне всё-таки кажется, что даже если смысл "как и нас тоже", всё равно слитно неправильно именно в таком обороте. Вот если бы можно было порядок изменить, тогда, пожалуй, можно было бы сказать "как и нас, также (=тоже)". То есть при исходном порядке слов всё же напрашивается смысл "в той же степени, что и", слитное "также" перед "как и" никак не хочется ставить.

Comment: Против правил, конечно, идти нельзя, но на мой взгляд, здесь нет сравнительно-приравнивающего смысла, поскольку просто ссылаются на "источник наибольшего беспокойства": и для нас, и для них он _один и тот же_, а не "в той же мере, что их, это беспокоит нас,"

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *Даллеса, **так же как и нас,** более всего беспокоит...*

Сравнить:

*Я знала, **так же как и она**, что рано или поздно наступит день, когда мы поневоле заговорим и простим друг другу долгое молчание.* Ч. Айтматов, Материнское поле.

Это пример из справочника, там союза со слитным написанием я не нахожу (он только в словаре Кузнецова).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_738

Comment: Вот да, один только словарь так считает. Маловато для того, чтобы на него полагаться... Я тоже не хотел бы считать правильным этот вариант.

Comment: Да, Артем, по Нацкорпусу счет 7350:447 в нашу пользу. Но оппоненты   (кстати, очень милые и уважаемые мною люди) вряд ли отступятся от своих убеждений, так что одним справочником их не убедишь.

Comment: Редкий случай, когда среди нестандартных подходов Кузнецова я нахожу прогрессивный проблеск :)

Comment: На Грамоте увидел подобную ошибку: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x. Только там это однозначно ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

**Второй ответ объясняет выбор написания союза, указанный в Справочнике по пунктуации.**

1) Мы  привыкли к тому, что нам часто приходится  отличать присоединительные союзы ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ (= И) от сочетаний указательных местоимений с частицей ЖЕ. Но там всё ясно: **союзы пишутся слитно, а местоимения раздельно.**

2) Вот мы и решаем, что здесь примерно такая же ситуация, но не тут-то было. **Грамота.ру предлагает нам в обоих вариантах раздельное написание:**  союз ТАК ЖЕ КАК И и сочетание  ТАК ЖЕ, КАК И.

3) **Что делать?** Правила нужно уважать, как и законы, которые нужно соблюдать.  С одной стороны,  у Грамоты нет законодательных функций, надо бы уточнить у Розенталя, а у него этот вопрос не рассматривается. Тогда остается Грамота.ру.

**Примечание.** Впрочем, у **РОЗЕНТАЛЯ** есть такой пример: Но: ***Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, так же как параллельная*** — без расчленения сложного союза; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

И есть у меня такое подозрение, что союз этот  **расчленять вообще нельзя,** так как местоимение ***как*** не может относиться к наречию *досрочно*. Тогда это просто присоединительный союз с раздельным написанием  ***так же***.

4) **Попробуем понять логику их  решения.**

***КАК И*** – это вариант сравнительного союза ***КАК*** с присоединительным значением, выраженным союзом ***И***.  Он используется  в обособленных оборотах, где вполне **справляется со своей  задачей** и не очень-то нуждается в помощниках.

Но помощники тем не менее находятся: союз ***ТАК ЖЕ КАК И*** – это всего лишь усиленный вариант союза ***КАК И***, но при этом ***ТАКЖЕ*** претендует на слитное написание, как если бы он был основным союзом.

И **можно было бы на это согласиться**, так как графика получается вполне симпатичная. Да вот какой неприятный момент: к союзному сочетанию норовят присоединиться еще и наречия ***совершенно, точно,*** а они к соседству  с союзом ТАКЖЕ  относятся крайне отрицательно.

5) Вот и приходится **нормировать две раздельные формы письма,** отличая союз *ТАК ЖЕ КАК И*  от местоименного сочетания *ТАК ЖЕ, КАК И*  **по следующим признакам**: по функции его основного компонента *КАК И* и  по отсутствию запятой  между частями союза.

**Примеры**

Толпа прибывала. Многие, **так же как и мы,** бросив на блокпостах машины, брели сюда пешком. [Елена Самойлова. // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2002]

Впрочем, Гусакову до того дело малое, **так же как и до фельдшера,** который всё время норовит отстать. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)

Я так до конца и не мог понять, чем я ему мил. Кроме того, что я кончил университет и был учителем, **так же как и его жена...** [Булат Окуджава. Искусство кройки и житья (1985)]