# Так же или также?

Tags: синтаксис, также

Относитесь к ней так же ( также) хорошо, как и ко мне.
Как правильно написать "также"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Относитесь к ней  **так же хорошо, как и** ко мне.*

**Пояснение**

1) Частицу ***ЖЕ*** можно убрать.

2) Указательное местоимение ***так*** грамматически относится к наречию *хорошо*: ***так хорошо***.

3) Повтор ***так...как*** обычно связан с раздельным написанием.

**Вариант со слитным написанием** (для сравнения):

*Относитесь к ней  тоже хорошо, как и ко мне.*

Comment: Оба предложенных альтернативных варианта - что без частицы "же", что с "тоже" вместо "так же", звучат просто ужасно. _"Тоже хорошо, как и ко мне"_ к тому же имеет другой смысл, и употребляется в другом контексте.

Comment: Добавлю, что ответ от @grizzly в [соседнем вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453769/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0) выглядит более обоснованным.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за внимание к моему ответу, но дело в том, что  здесь двух "ужасных" альтернативных вариантов. В первом варианте частицу ЖЕ убираем для проверки (прием такой есть), чтобы убедиться, что "так" относится именно к наречию (к использованию в речи этот вариант не предназначен). Второй вариант тоже скорее учебный, не для образцового стиля. Его смысл в том, что он возможен при наличии во второй части составного союза "как и". Если бы там был союз "как", то этот вариант был бы грамматически невозможен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите Ваше замечание в ответ @grizzly, а то оно здесь затеряется. Там же я и отвечу.

Comment: Какое замечание - о том, что мне кажется верным ответ @grizzly? Я просто плюсанул его ответ, какой смысл это писать словами? Если вы считаете нужным с ним поспорить, то отвечать лучше прямо ему, а не мне.

Comment: Я пока ничего не считаю, в той теме на мой ответ не поступило критики, так с кем же мне спорить? Я даю альтернативный ответ, если не согласна с предыдущими ответами, и в этом ответе  уже объяснена моя позиция.  По "протоколу" такие действия более правильны, чем если бы, дав свой ответ, я начала бы критиковать чужие.

Comment: Я вашу позицию понимаю, но у меня нет аргументированных или хотя бы просто осмысленных замечаний, чтобы писать там комментарий. Просто писать "и я того же мнения"? Ну, это как-то... Там, кстати, к вашему ответу @Артём Луговой написал замечание, так что критика вам все-таки поступила.

Comment: Спасибо за искренний ответ, и я, скорее всего, попробую упрочить свою позицию в той теме.

Comment: В этом вопросе случай бесспорен до скуки. А если вариант с другим смыслом, по кузнецовской "лицензии"? _Относитесь к ней хорошо, также как и ко мне._ ("...ко мне тоже надо бы хорошо относиться).

Comment: Неоднозначный смысл, некорректная стилистика. В устной речи ваше слитное написание "также" никто не услышит. Вариант редактирования: Относитесь к ней хорошо, да и  ко мне тоже. Вот так...

Comment: В устной речи другая расстановка пауз по отношению к варианту "равнохорошести отношения" (пунктуация на письме это отражает), поэтому дойдёт до собеседника. Оттенок "стилистичеки предпочтительного" варианта несколько отличается: в моём примере вторая часть реплики подчёркивает требование хорошего отношения к себе как "само собой разумеющееся". Что касается кузнецовской слитности, то она остаётся спорной в силу фактической непризнанности. Возможно, позже это изменится.